# Where does Amy Farrah Fowler work?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

Wikipedia and the BBT wiki both say she's a neurobiologist, but I can't find any indication as to where she works.  She's not at Cal Tech with the guys, except when she specifically goes there for a project.   Is it ever specified?

Comment: I don't think it's ever stated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no information on Amy's job in or out of universe at this time. All we know is that it is not Caltech, she's a researcher, and was kicked off the monkey project due to some mutual poop throwing.

Update: As of Season 7, Amy got moved to Caltech, but the specifics of the arrangement isn't detailed. We do not know if she got hired there, under a research grant, a collaboration between two universities or a private company and Caltech, or even if the space is just rented. This seems to have ended as of Season 10.

Comment: You get my UV for *poop throwing*. :)

Answer (score 4):

In 'The Re-Entry Minimization' Amy suggests going to the UCLA cadaver lab to play real-life Operation.  If she has privileges there, perhaps that's where she works.

Answer (score 4):

In The Vacation Solution there was a research poster outside Amy's lab. I got curious and googled it, and what visible parts of the title and authors seem to match [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3655708/) with authors from UCLA, Brown University and Germany. Since universities usually display their own researchers' published posters I'd assume that it is in UCLA.